# C++ Error: use of undefined type

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `Friend2` is a friend of `Friend1`. After `Friend2` accesses the `Friend1`'s private member variable, I want `Friend1` to be able to access the `Friend2`'s public member functions. So I decided to use composition inside `Friend1`. However, the compiler shows me the error:

```
use of undefined type 'friend2'
```

Then, I tried another way, making `Friend1` a friend of `Friend2` too. But I still got the same error. Would anyone teach me the way to solve? Thx a lot!

```
#ifndef FRIEND1_H
#define FRIEND1_H

class friend2;

class friend1 {
  private:
    int x;
    public:
    friend1();

    int comp(friend2* f2o);

    friend class friend2;
    };

    friend1::friend1() {
      x = 1;
    }

    int friend1::comp(friend2* f2o) {
      return f2o->getxx(); //the error : use of undefined type 
    }

#endif
```

```
#ifndef FRIEND2_H
#define FRIEND2_H

#include "friend1.h"
#include <iostream>

class friend2 {
  private:
    int xx;
    public:
    friend2();
    void p(friend1* f1o);

    int getxx() const;

    friend class friend1;
    };

    friend2::friend2() {}

    void friend2::p(friend1* f1o) {
      xx = f1o->x;
    }

    int friend2::getxx() const {
      return xx;
    }

#endif
```

Also, is composition or friend class the better way to do this? Why?

Comment: I guess what you need is to have a `friend1.cpp` file including both `friend1.h` and `friend2.h`, then the implementation of `friend1::comp()` gets to know friend2's structure.

Comment: Thx for your reply first :) After your instruction, the original error has gone. But LNK1169 and LNK2005 errors appear, and i have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `//the error : use of undefined type` because `class Friend2` is only declared, not defined at that point. To solve this move `int friend1::comp(friend2* f2o)` implementation to `friend1.cpp` and include `friend2.h` from there.

**UPDATE** In general, if two classes are mutual friends (and even if only one of them is a friend to another), it's a good reason to think about the design.

Comment: Thx for your reply too :) the original error has gone. But LNK1169 and LNK2005 errors appear, do u know why?

Comment: @WaiLokChan What exactly do the error messages say? Perhaps there is a non-inline function, or global variable defined in one of *.h files.

Comment: Oh, after i separated friend2.h into friend2.h(declaration) and friend2.cpp(definition), the problem was solved so nicely. Although I don't quite understand the mechanism behind it, i am so glad that the program can run now! Thank you so much for your help, @Anton Savin :)

Comment: @WaiLokChan You're welcome (and feel free to mark the answer as accepted :) The mechanism is that your unsplit friend2.h was included in several .cpp files so if you had global functions or variables defined there, the code for them was generated several times, which gave you linker errors.